# cmv-app 2.0 connect.json is not a function

Tags: configurable-map-viewer, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, node-js

I am using the Dev branch of the cmv-app and having trouble getting up and running out of the box. It looks like I am unable to start the web server - error says `connect.json is not a function`.

I installed the node dependencies as described in the 1.3.4 docs. Not sure if anything has changed in 2.0.0 as far as setting up the dev environment. Are there docs specifically for 2.0.0?

Comment: Which version of the ArcGIS API for JavaScript are you using?

Comment: same as the dev branch - 3.20 compact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that newer versions of `grunt-contrib-connect` require the use of an additional nodejs package `body-parser` to enable the same functionality. I submitted a [new Pull Request](https://github.com/cmv/cmv-app/pull/669) in the cmv-app repo which addresses this.

This hasn't been tested extensively. I did a basic test the use of `grunt connect:dev` and the middleware proxy. Most of the current cmv core developers such as myself do not use this approach for a development environment so it doesn't get much attention. Personally, I just use a simple python-based web server. Updates to the CMV docs to describe alternative would be a good idea.